# BitPay payment callback not working

Tags: php, callback, paypal-ipn

i'm currently working on implementing BitPay into my site and don't appear to get the notifications from the IPN.

I'm using their given library to make this easier. https://github.com/bitpay/php-client

Here is the callback code i'm currently using, it's only for testing purposes as of now:

```
<?php
require_once '../../helpers/bp_lib.php';
require_once '../../helpers/bp_options.php';
file_put_contents('bitpay.txt', json_encode(bpVerifyNotification()));
file_put_contents('bitpay2.txt', json_encode($_POST));
```

I'm using a valid API key, pointing it to the right place, and am receiving the payments, so I must be doing something else wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: check the access logs to see if your url is actully being 'hit' by BitPay

Comment: @Dagon Where do I find the access logs? They don't seem to be publicly displayed on the dashboard.

Comment: We could assume as long as his PHP file has the correct permissions, it'd be writing to them text files if it was being hit.

Comment: Yeah it appears to be a permission error.  Got it all fixed and working.

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer? Thanks.